# Can't pass file containing whitespace as command-line argument to SMS-sending Python script in Ubuntu Touch in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: bash, python, ubuntu-touch, scripts, sms

I can send text messages by SMS using the command:

```
$ /usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms /ril_0 07123456789 "iorem ipsum est" 0
```

Where `/ril_0` is the SIM card/modem, `07123456789` is the telephone number, `"iorem ipsum est"` is the text to be sent and the last `0` is (I think) a boolean determining whether or not the script will request a delivery report.

This works fine, and produces the output:

```
Send message using modem /ril_0 ...
/ril_0/message_20C76858222F2CDF61342FC317BF53AC4B763441
```

However, this doesn't seem to work:

```
$ echo '"iorem ipsum est"' > textfile
$ /usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms /ril_0 07123456789 $(cat textfile) 0
```

I tried a few permutations, backticks and so forth; none of them work and they all produce output like this:

```
Send message using modem /ril_1 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms", line 31, in <module>
    mm.SetProperty("UseDeliveryReports", dbus.Boolean(int(sys.argv[3])))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"iorem'
```

`/ril_1` is where the second SIM card would be (if there were one), and I guess the rest is a stack trace?

For what it's worth, this works fine:

```
$ echo '"iorem"' > textfile
$ /usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms /ril_0 07123456789 $(cat textfile) 0
```

So I guess the problem lies in the way `$()` handles output containing whitespace?

I've pasted the contents of `/usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms` to http://pastebin.com/u8gHMc5R (and of course the source is available to download from Ubuntu, here http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/vivid/ofono-scripts).

I don't really want to mess with the original Python script (even if I knew any Python, which I don't!), but if there isn't a shell solution that I don't know (something using pipes or xargs, maybe?) I wouldn't be against the idea of another script which makes use of the original one, or something.

My system is a BQ Aquaris running 15.04 (r23). In case it makes a difference somehow, I'm running all these commands via ssh rather than typing them into the phone.

Any help much appreciated. Oh, and if I should be posting this somewhere else, for instance on Stack Overflow or something because of all the Python, please do let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes to wrap the command substitution. Also either use single quotes or use double quotes in the `echo` command, there's no need to use both:

```
echo 'iorem ipsum est' > textfile
/usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms /ril_0 07123456789 "$(cat textfile)" 0
```

Comment: I think he was thinking both would mean `$(cat textfile)` would yield `"foo bar"` instead of `\"foo bar\"`